# How to log in to TDAmeritrade with Ruby Mechanize GEM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mechanize

I'm using Ruby with the Mechanize GEM to log in to TDAmeritrade's website.

I try to execute: `page = agent.get('https://invest.ameritrade.com/grid/p/login')` and it returns page.forms as follows:

`2.0.0-p0 :049 > page.forms`
`=> [#<Mechanize::Form`
`{name nil}`
`{method "POST"}`
`{action "https://invest.ameritrade.com/grid/p/login"}`
`{fields`
`[hidden:0x5b6684a type: hidden name: mAction value: submit]`
`[hidden:0x5b665a2 type: hidden name: fp_browser value: ]`
`[hidden:0x5b66386 type: hidden name: fp_screen value: ]`
`[hidden:0x5b661e2 type: hidden name: fp_software value: ]`
`[hidden:0x5b6f36e type: hidden name: fp_timezone value: ]`
`[hidden:0x5b6ffb2 type: hidden name: fp_language value: ]`
`[hidden:0x5b6fe5e type: hidden name: fp_java value: ]`
`[hidden:0x5b6fcc4 type: hidden name: fp_cookie value: ]`
`[hidden:0x5b6fbfc type: hidden name: flashVersion value: ]`
`[selectlist:0x5b6f756 type:  name: ldl value: main:home]}`
`{radiobuttons}`
`{checkboxes}`
`{file_uploads}`
`{buttons [button:0x5b6eafe type: submit name:  value: ]}>`
`]`

As you can see, neither the username nor password fields are shown even though they can be seen on the website in a browser. How do I log in to TDAmeritrade with my Ruby script using the Mechanize GEM (http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the usual way: `form['username'] = 'my user name'` ?

Comment: I tried using the following URL instead: `http://www.ameritrade.com`. With that I am able to see tdUsername and tdPassword in the form that is returned. I fill those in and submit but I just receive the same page back. It doesn't log me in.

Comment: In that case you're on your own. Questions like 'how do I log in to TDAmeritrade' are really too specific to be answered here. You might consider hiring someone to help you.

Comment: I don't think it's very specific. TDAmeritrade is used by millions of people. I'm sure there are many programmers out there that would like to programmatically access their TDAmeritrade accounts. I'll post this question to the Mechanize mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

For sites that login via a POST request, you can manually capture the XHR in something like Firebug and replicate it in your code.

For example, the site you have listed has a bunch of hidden fields that get added on submission of a username and password. Luckily, you can pass a hash to a POST request call on your Mechanize::Agent.

> @agent.post("https://invest.ameritrade.com/grid/p/login",
>   {"tbPassword" => yourPass, "tbUsername" => yourUsername})

Of course you'll need to add the additional fields as well.

example POST XHR from Firebug for your example site

```
flashVersion    11.9.900
fp_browser  mozilla/5.0 (macintosh; intel mac os x 10.8; rv:24.0) gecko/20100101 firefox/24.0|5.0 (Macintosh)|MacIntel
fp_cookie   1
fp_java 1
fp_language lang=en-US|syslang=|userlang=
fp_screen   24|2560|1440|1440
fp_software 
fp_timezone -4
ldl main:home
mAction submit
tbPassword  yourPassword
tbUsername  yourUsername
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding those fields to my post as well but am still not being logged in.

Comment: There's likely more fields that are required than just here. Does the returned page produce any errors? You can set page = @agent.post and pp that out.

Comment: The page does not produce any errors. Here's what it returned: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Z6YtX2CM

Comment: BTW, I have no problems logging into Facebook using Mechanize. Of course, Facebook doesn't have all of these hidden fields. I also used Burp Suite to analyze the post data and it looks like I have all of the hidden fields set correct. One thing I noticed was that in Burp Suite the fp_screen field is set using URL encoding to: `fp_screen=24%7C1440%7C900%7C876&` instead of what I have set it to in Ruby: `tdf.fp_screen = '24|1440|900|876'`. I don't know if Mechanize handles the URL encoding for me. I guess I could try to set it as Burp Suite shows it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You might run into problems with mechanize on different sites that implement javascript. You might want to try using the [watir-webdriver](http://watirwebdriver.com) or if it's a site that has a lot of javascript use you might be better off using [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org).